# Shell script traversing the all subdirectories and modifying the content of files

Tags: shell, unix

I  need to modify a number of files inside a directory. I need to modify all those files which contain particular text and have to replace with some new text.

So I thought of writing a shell script which will traverse through all the subdirectories and modify the content but I'm having problem while traversing the all possible directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to traverse through subdirectories looking for files and then pass them on to `sed` to search and replace for text.

e.g.

```
find /some/directory -type f -name "*.txt" -print -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

will find all txt files and replace foo with bar in them.

The `-i` makes sed change the files in-place. You can also supply a backup-suffix to sed if you want the files backed up before being changed.

Comment: there's no need to use `-print` and you are using the wrong pattern for `-name`

Comment: You can use `-i.bak` in case you'd like to create backup files (`.bak` extension in this case).

Answer (score 1):

GNU find

```
find /some_path -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' "{}" +;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/examples/functions/recurse

:)

Answer (score 0):

You want [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in $(find  | grep txt$)
do
   echo $n
   modify_content.sh $n
done
```